# TEXTVIEW Click is not working in android

Tags: android, onclick, textview

```
package com.jd.multileveltreelistview;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MultilevelTreeListView extends Activity 
{
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView mainList;
    ArrayList<Entity>arrTrades;
    public static int totcnt = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.treelist);
        mainList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.currentpending_list);
        mainList.setDividerHeight(4);
        arrTrades=new ArrayList<Entity>();

        try {
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel);
        textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        }
                 });
        } catch(Exception e) { }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        if(arrTrades.size()==0){
            populateList();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    public Entity getEntity(int level,int haschild){
        Entity E=new Entity();
        E.Name="Level "+level;
        E.Name= " S.Viswanathan " + totcnt + "\n";
        E.Name = E.Name + "Role: Group Leader " + "\n";
        E.Name = E.Name + "Mail: s.vishy@tcscom " + "\n";
        E.Name = E.Name + "Phone:  9600421518";
        totcnt = totcnt + 1;
        E.isOpened=false;
        E.level=level;
        E.HasChild=haschild;
        return E;
    }
    public void populateList()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                    arrTrades.add(getEntity(0, 1));
            }
            adapter=new ListAdapter(MultilevelTreeListView.this, R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel, arrTrades);
            mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(" populateList Exception",""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void CellTextClick()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void CellButtonClick(View v){
        try{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button b=(Button)v;
            int index;
            index=(Integer) b.getTag();
            if(b.getText().toString().equals("+")){
                b.setText("-");
                Entity temp[]=new Entity[5];
                int PLevel=arrTrades.get(index).level+1;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    temp[i]=getEntity(PLevel, 1);
                }
                arrTrades.get(index).isOpened=true;
                if(temp!=null){
                    int addindex=index+1;
                    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                        arrTrades.add(addindex, temp[i]);
                        addindex++;
                    }
                }
                temp=null;
            }
            else{
                b.setText("+");
                arrTrades.get(index).isOpened=false;
                    int removeindex=index+1;
                    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                        if(arrTrades.get(removeindex).isOpened){
                            removeChilds(removeindex);
                        }
                        arrTrades.remove(removeindex);
                    }
                }


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("Error=", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void removeChilds(int index){
        try {
                int removeindex=index+1;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    if(arrTrades.get(removeindex).isOpened){
                        removeChilds(removeindex);
                    }
                    arrTrades.remove(removeindex);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Errro=", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
02-25 11:34:50.965: E/AndroidRuntime(6907): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jd.multileveltreelistview/com.jd.multileveltreelistview.MultilevelTreeListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at com.jd.multileveltreelistview.MultilevelTreeListView.onCreate(MultilevelTreeListView.java:29)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-25 11:34:50.980: E/AndroidRuntime(6907):     ... 11 more
```

I want user perform some activities on Textview Click, but that part is not invoked properly in my program.Please see the XML File, Java Program and also the particular function of clickable event.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"

        android:id="@+id/row">
           <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/row_cell_text_dummy_multilevel"
        android:singleLine="false"  />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/row_cell_btn_multilevel"
        android:onClick="CellButtonClick"

        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="CellTextClick"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="center|left"/>
      </LinearLayout> 
      </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want user to click the Text view also, so that i can do some function. But the below module in the program is not called.Java Program which contains the above code, the CellTextClick should be called in the below program, but its not invoked.

```
package com.jd.multileveltreelistview;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MultilevelTreeListView extends Activity 
{
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView mainList;
    ArrayList<Entity>arrTrades;
    public static int totcnt = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.treelist);
        mainList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.currentpending_list);
        mainList.setDividerHeight(4);
        arrTrades=new ArrayList<Entity>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        if(arrTrades.size()==0){
            populateList();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    public Entity getEntity(int level,int haschild){
        Entity E=new Entity();
        E.Name="Level "+level;
        E.Name= " S.Viswanathan " + totcnt + "\n";
        E.Name = E.Name + "Role: Group Leader " + "\n";
        E.Name = E.Name + "Mail: s.vishy@tcscom " + "\n";
        E.Name = E.Name + "Phone:  9600421518";
        totcnt = totcnt + 1;
        E.isOpened=false;
        E.level=level;
        E.HasChild=haschild;
        return E;
    }
    public void populateList()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                    arrTrades.add(getEntity(0, 1));
            }
            adapter=new ListAdapter(MultilevelTreeListView.this, R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel, arrTrades);
            mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(" populateList Exception",""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void CellTextClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void CellButtonClick(View v){
        try{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button b=(Button)v;
            int index;
            index=(Integer) b.getTag();
            if(b.getText().toString().equals("+")){
                b.setText("-");
                Entity temp[]=new Entity[5];
                int PLevel=arrTrades.get(index).level+1;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    temp[i]=getEntity(PLevel, 1);
                }
                arrTrades.get(index).isOpened=true;
                if(temp!=null){
                    int addindex=index+1;
                    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                        arrTrades.add(addindex, temp[i]);
                        addindex++;
                    }
                }
                temp=null;
            }
            else{
                b.setText("+");
                arrTrades.get(index).isOpened=false;
                    int removeindex=index+1;
                    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                        if(arrTrades.get(removeindex).isOpened){
                            removeChilds(removeindex);
                        }
                        arrTrades.remove(removeindex);
                    }
                }


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("Error=", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void removeChilds(int index){
        try {
                int removeindex=index+1;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    if(arrTrades.get(removeindex).isOpened){
                        removeChilds(removeindex);
                    }
                    arrTrades.remove(removeindex);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Errro=", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the click listener for textview?

Comment: set your listener on java instead define that on `xml` file

Comment: @SPSumit: android:onClick="CellTextClick" working for TextView also.

Comment: indicate line 29 @ `MultilevelTreeListView`

Comment: textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: so `textview` is null, make sure `row_cell_text_multilevel` be exists on `treelist`

Comment: it exists in treelist

Comment: clean your project and run again, if you run on real device first uninstall then install  again

Comment: same error after uninstall also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it out

```
    Textview tv;
  tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.row_cell_text_dummy_multilevel);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toast();

        }

        private void toast() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("click", "sucss");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
    textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
            });
```

Comment: Not working this option....                                               TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel);
     textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                     }
             });

Comment: this has to be worked. please make sure id of TextView is proper.

Comment: you are getting null pointer exception...have you create id for textview in xml?

Comment: also remove  android:onClick="CellTextClick" from xml.

Comment: pass your code to me..so that i can solve the issue. mail your code at sumit.sptechnolab@gmail.com

Comment: Send from my gmail. id.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Sumit.  Since it is present in the holder, i need to set the listener in that area. holder.txtName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(contx, "Answer As of Now : INGU VANTHEN",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="center|left"/>
```

Activity

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.tv1:
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

default:
    break;
                }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give an id to the textview and try again 
or 
Try this:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **id** to your textview
XML:-

```
<TextView 
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:gravity="center|left"/>
```

Activity:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.txt:
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer As of Now : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

default:
    break;
                }
       }
});
```

Hope it will work !!

Updated Answer:--

Write this,

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_cell_text_dummy_multilevel);
```

instead of this

```
 TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_cell_text_multilevel);
```

As you had give your `button id` to your `textView`, thats why you are getting null pointer exception...

Comment: dear give id to text view in xml

Comment: Gave.   <TextView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
  android:onClick="CellTextClick"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/row_cell_text_multilevel"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        
        />

Comment: give (R.id.row_cell_text_dummy_multilevel) id to your textView

Answer (score 0):

Add id to the textview

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="CellTextClick"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="center|left"/>
```

And add onclick listener

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    System.out.println("Text clicked");

            }
        });
```

Comment: not working, pls refer the post again for errors. I updated now.